# I don't know why the columns are changed (origin : 'a', 'b', 'c' → to_csv : "a,b,c")

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I use pandas in python and wanna remove unnecessary rows at csv file

I'm so confused this situation

↓ Before edit

```
This is a example
A
B
C
fruit, film, vehicle
apple, Harry potter, Hyundai
banana, Avengers, Ford
```

↓ edited

```
,0
0 "fruit, film, vehicle"
1 "apple, Harry potter, Hyundai"
2 "banana, Avengers, Ford"
```

Left side is origin file and Right side is edited
You can see the unnecessary rows at Left
so i remove that rows using this code

**.drop(index=[0,1,2,3,4])**

After i applied, the columns(절점  ,값 (N/m^2)  ,X (mm)  ,Y (mm)  ,Z (mm)) are tied like Right side

How can i solve this problem?
Can i separate this string??
i wanna make this matrix has 6 columns (the right side has only 2 columns)

Before you comment, i receive this file via CAD program so i don't wanna edit this by myself

Sorry for my English skill : (

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to link to outside media, as these links can go stale. Could you modify your question to include to example directly?

Comment: @PirateNinjas i edited my post. i added example

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand what you need exacly but if your input always looks same, and you want get DF with header contains (X(mm) etc. )
you can take everything after this row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['chnesseeee stuff1','X(mm)',1755,5.334],
                   'B': ['chinesseeee stuff 2','Y(mm)',1445,23.23],
                   })
print(df)
                   A                    B
0  chnesseeee stuff1  chinesseeee stuff 2
1              X(mm)                Y(mm)
2               1755                 1445
3              5.334                23.23
df['temp'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'(X\(mm\))').ffill()
df=df.dropna(subset=['temp'])
del df['temp']
print(df)
       A      B
1  X(mm)  Y(mm)
2   1755   1445
3  5.334  23.23
```